# Specify to use native .Net class and not Mono's implementation in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

When working on a Unity IL2CPP .Net Framework project, is it possible to force the application to use the native .Net 4.8 version of a specific class instead of the Mono implementation?

---

I don't intend replace mono entirely for the whole app, I only want the windows native `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` class to be used instead of Unity/Mono's version.

I ask this because the Unity/Mono port is missing functionality I need, namely:

1. Locating X509Certificates in the localmachine "MY" store.
2. Instantiating a certificate reference using an IntPtr to the certificate itself.

With regards to 1, Unity have indicated they [dgaf](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/x509store-is-empty-in-unity-but-has-certificates-in-pure-c-number-console-application) about supporting it. Unity standard practice is to embed the private key certificate and password into the unity app, or to use their SSL networking implementation. (What about using certificate keystore for non-ssl, non-networking key management/)

For 2, I've implemented a C++ external dll that looks up the certificate and passes it's pointer back to Unity, however Unity's constructor for X509Certificates that takes an IntPrt throws a PlatformNotSupported error when called.

I've manually extracted the entire .Net 4.8 X509Certificates namespace from the MSDN source to workaround the limitation, however there's still an [InternalCall](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/x509certificates/x509utils.cs,09001a985fcd3648,references) which breaks with a cryptic error when called:

```
System.MissingMethodException:  assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
at (wrapper managed-to-native)
Me.X509Utils._DuplicateCertContext(intptr,USAF.FourTS.Encipherment.SafeCertContextHandle&)
```

Comment: You can use the `using` directive to specify from which namespaces you want to use (by aliasing the namespace) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#using-alias

Comment: Unity's migration to .NET Core is going to finish soon, https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-future-net-development-status.1092205/page-37 Except that I don't think a small group of developers can hack too much.

Comment: @Flydog unfortunately, `Using` is still going to use the underlying mono port of .Net. What I need is more akin to a platform Invoke between mono's port and the real .Net.

Comment: @LexLi I'll be much happier when they are finished and I no longer need to worry about .Net capability X not being supported or .Net method Y throwing a not Implemented exception for future projects. That said, there were so many unity systems broken or obsoleted between unity 2018 and 2022 that I'll likely never upgrade this project beyond it's current version.